# Should we have a webupd8 tag?

Tags: discussion

[Web Upd8](http://webupd8.org) is a successful site that offers "Daily Ubuntu / Linux news and application reviews".  It has a large number of applications included in its main PPA (`ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`) and other PPAs, including a popular Java installer, MDM, a patched NotifyOSD, and a lot of GTK and conky themes.

Is this large enough to make a tag ([webupd8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/webupd8) or similar) out of?  If not, can someone direct me to a resource on tags?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's not a need to create a tag and if there is please post an example where it could be best applied (in your opinion). We don't arbitrarily create tags, they get created when they're needed when a question is asked. [webupd8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/webupd8) has no meaning to a post and doesn't provide any real tagging criteria. Instead it's just a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and by that definition a bad tag.

Comment: Possibly [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/233008/37700) (IMO).

Comment: Thanks for the resource.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah, that tag really wouldn't apply there. It has nothing to do with the question and would be considered a meta tag

Comment: Well, they're having a problem with the webupd8 ppa, that's more than nothing.  Not really important though anyways. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why would it be a meta-tag? It's a subject, after all. We have a "Google" tag, so another tag for a known organization doesn't seem too out-of-context or subjective.

Comment: The google tag needs cleaning, most are referring to Google Chrome, or a Google Service like Google Reader. Just because a tag exists doesn't make it a good tag.